# Rails images are loading in one controller and not the other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The same images in my rails app are loading in one controller and not the other.

In my static_pages/about.html.erb I have an image that loads just fine:

```
<img src="assets/danish_flag.gif" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="Denmark" height = "28px" width = "36px">
```

In my users/show.html.erb I have a partial

```
<%= render partial: "layouts/backdrop", locals: { :user => @user } %>
```

which loads fine besides for the image tag located in it which is the same as the image in my static_pages image:

```
<img src="assets/danish_flag.gif" class ="img-responsive img-circle" alt="Denmark 4eva" height="28px" width ="36px">
```

I have also tried:

```
<img src="assets/images/danish_flag.gif" class ="img-responsive img-circle" alt="Denmark 4eva" height="28px" width ="36px">
```

but neither loads.  A blank box with a small question mark inside is loaded instead.

If I inspect the source and click the path which should link to the image I just get a 404 resource not loaded.

Why is this happening?  I have several images like this which load perfectly fine in the static_pages controller views, and do not load in my other controllers' views (the same images).

The images are located in assets/images.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Rails assets helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html) to generate the correct path for you:

```
<%= image_tag( 'danish_flag.gif', 
                class: "img-responsive img-circle", 
                alt: "Denmark 4eva",
                height: 28,
                width: 36
) %>
```